# Why am I still receiving old—and resolved—Amber alerts on my Android phone?

Tags: sms

For the past 2 months, every few days to a week, I've been getting an Amber alert. Oddly, though, it's the same one every time.

The notification reads as follows

> *Messages 3/13/19*
>
> Emergency Alerts
>
> AMBER Alert: Paradise- 86 Camo F-250 MI/DQQ5813.  Suspect is white male.  Check local media.

Yeah, I just got that today, May 3, 2019.

Besides being utterly confused at the formatting, and being too far away to do anything, The alert is just plain old.

I looked up the license plate and the missing child and the abducters were found March 14th.

A Google search trying to figure out why this alert is broken only rendered instructions on how to turn Amber alerts off. I don't want to do that. I do not want to disable Amber alerts, I just want my Amber alerts to be correct.

I am using a different SMS app than the default ([Silence](https://silence.im)) , and maybe that has something to do with it? But I doubt it. However, when I go to click on the notification, it tries to open up my old app. I don't want it to do so because I hate dumping my messages back and forth between the two apps.

I am concerned that the old message is displaying whenever I get a new emergency message, and therefore I can’t see the new messages. What might be causing this and how might I be able to fix it?